# Delete default route via WinAPI

Tags: winapi, networking

I would like to implement deletion of the default route via WinAPI:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
```

It looks like route is doing via undocumented Nsi* calls. Is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

DeleteIpForwardEntry does the trick:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

// Execute as admin
int main()
{
    ULONG size = 10000;

    PMIB_IPFORWARDTABLE table = (PMIB_IPFORWARDTABLE)malloc(size);

    memset(table, 0, size);

    GetIpForwardTable(table,&size,true);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int) table->dwNumEntries; i++) {

        // Default route 0.0.0.0
        if(table->table[i].dwForwardDest == 0)
        {
            DWORD ret = DeleteIpForwardEntry(&table->table[i]);
            printf("Ret: %X\n", ret);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```